# Programm to edit .sdi files for windows

Tags: openoffice.org

I want to edit a `.sdi` file which is used in a Open Office file. I can open it with the OO Calc but after saving that it isn't working anymore. I read about this `sCal` Linux program. But I can't find something similar for windows.

Comment: Sorry, this is a forum to get help with specific programming issues. This is _not_ a general help forum.

Comment: But just to complete this post, I found the mistake

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that Open Office Calc used the `;` and the `whitespaces`.

It must be just `whitespaces`